# How to make ImageMagick Imagick class available?

Tags: php, imagemagick

This is a really amateur question but I've installed [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) from the ports on my FreeBSD.

However when I use

```
$image = new Imagick($filename);
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /usr/local/www/test.php on line 1

How do I make this class accessible to the scripts?

Answer (score 3):

> pecl install imagick

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php).

Answer (score 2):

You installed the ImageMagick suite itself, which does not provide any interface to PHP. You also need to install the [PECL Imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) extension.

FreeBSD has a [port](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=pecl-imagick&stype=all&sektion=all) available for this - `graphics/pecl-imagick`.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to get/build the accompanying PHP library that interfaces with Image Magick. Then add it to your php.ini with something like:

```
extension=php5-imagick.so
```

There is also a OS X / Darwin port available [here](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=magick).

Comment: I was getting the same error after doing the PECL install and adding the extension to my php.ini (and restarting Apache) did the trick.

Comment: For Debian `apt-get install php5-imagic imagemagick` and then in `/etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini` uncomment `extension=imagick.so` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install imagemagick && apt-get install php-imagick
```

(Ubuntu)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!